# Can I inject intercom.io using a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, intercom, intercom.js

I can't seem to inject it through a normal injection.

The code is the standard script of intercom put in an src/inject/inject.js file

Here is my manifest file

```
{
  "name": "CHANGE THIS : Extension boilerplate",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "This extension was created with the awesome extensionizr.com",
  "homepage_url": "http://extensionizr.com",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  },
  "default_locale": "en",
  "background": {
    "page": "src/bg/background.html",
    "persistent": true
  },
  "permissions": [
    "https://*/*",
    " http://*/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "src/inject/inject.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: To make the question answerable, describe what happens now, and what you want to happen instead. Include error messages from devtools console (in the web page and in the background page), if present.

Comment: Nothing happens. No error messages.

Comment: "Nothing happens" when you do what exactly?

Comment: @NilayModi Did you find a way to do this? having the same issue.